# Change default animation on StackView

Tags: android, animation, stackview

Is it possible to change the default animation (in/out) of Android StackView (using native Android methods)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-controls-stackview.html#popEnter-prop

Transitions

The animations can be customized by assigning different Transitions for the pushEnter, pushExit, popEnter, popExit, replaceEnter, and replaceExit properties of StackView.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Alexey! But I was looking for something using the native framework. I will edit the question to make that clear.